# Qt Creator: how to debug and watch widget's properties?

Tags: debugging, qt, qt-creator

I have a form and several widgets on it. Say, I have the following code and breakpoint on this line:

```
ui->labTitle->setMinimumHeight(64);
```

And I would like to know which height the labTitle has now. Where and how??? If I try to add ui->labTitle into watches list it says it doesn't know what is it. Maybe I need to adjust some debug settings but I don't know what exactly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ui->labTitle` is actually `this->ui->labTitle`, so it's only valid when being in a context where `this` pointer is valid and points to the your main window. Adding to the watches should work, but don't forget the parantheses:

```
this->ui->labTitle->minimumHeight()
```

Comment: Didn't help, I don't know why, it still <invalid> and <unknown>, even after CONFIG += debug added.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check is to make sure your `.pro` file contains a config setting that specifies "debug" like this:

```
CONFIG += debug
```